# Share surface to other app

Tags: android, surfaceview

I created surface that have grid. After adding on it some objects(circle, photos) I want to share it without grid. Can anyone help me to solve my problem. Here is my code and see  my surface with grid attached. [surfaceview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94SIC.jpg).

```
 artBoard.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = artBoard.getDrawingCache();
        String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,"title", null);
        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
        final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

artbord is my surfaceview.

[image]

Comment: So... draw it a second time, without the grid? It's not clear what you're having trouble with.